# SQL JOIN IN Select

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a table with many dates (`Registered`) for one `ID`. I want to return only the oldest date for each `ID` but I'm doing something wrong. I guess in the `AND s.ID IN...` part of the first `JOIN`.

Can someone please help me understand what I do wrong?

```
SELECT i.ID, MIN(s.Registered) AS 'Date', l.Name AS 'Status'    
FROM Installation i
JOIN StatusLog s ON s.InstallationID = i.ID AND s.ID IN 
    (SELECT MIN(Registered) 
     FROM statuslog 
     WHERE status IN(5)
     GROUP BY Installationid)
JOIN StatusList l ON l.ID = s.Status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query :-

```
SELECT
i.ID,
MIN(s.Registered) AS 'Date',
l.Name AS 'Status'

FROM Installation i
JOIN StatusLog s ON s.InstallationID = i.ID AND s.status=5
JOIN StatusList l ON l.ID = s.Status
group by i.ID,l.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try something like this

```
SELECT
 i.ID
 ,MIN(s.Registered) AS 'Date'
 ,l.Name AS 'Status'

FROM Installation i
JOIN StatusLog s ON s.InstallationID = i.ID AND s.ID IN 
       (select MIN(Registered) from statuslog where status=5 group by Installationid)
JOIN StatusList l ON l.ID = s.Status
group by i.ID,l.Name
```